# angular aws-sdk - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk-nodejs

Angular Code:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

try {
      AWS.config.update({
          accessKeyId:config.access_id,
          secretAccessKey:config.access_key,
          region:config.region
        })
      
      const s3 = new AWS.S3();
      const files = s3.listObjectsV2({
        Bucket:config.bucket_name
      }).promise();
      console.log(files);
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
```

CORS configuration of bucket:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Error message in console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2' from origin 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Cloudfront configuration:

[image]

Bucket is private. Block all public access is enabled. No static website hosting. I am trying to list files from private bucket.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved. Created new private bucket and tried adding same configuration. Error occurred because I was using the bucket whose Bucket policy was set So it was restricting access it seems.